# Angular. Get server response in catchError

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using standard http service to send requests to server.
Sometimes server returns data with 503 HTTP error.

```
http.post<...>(url, body).pipe(map(result => {
      console.log(result);
      return result;
    }),
      catchError(err => throwError(err)));
```

I fall into ***catchError*** every time server returns HTTP error code. What I want to do - is to access the whole HTTP response (that contains some useful data even if HTTP error is returned within response).

How can I do that?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subscribe the request and catch the error like this:

```
 this.http.post(url, body).subscribe(
  data => {
     console.log(data);
  },
  err => {
     console.log(err);  // err.error for example for specific attribute
  });
```

I hope this is helpfull.